# To design the system of a rectangular small shaft moving in and out in a completely mechanical way without remote control

Tags: mechanisms, robotics, linear-motion

In my setup , I have designed a system in which a body will rotate and execute rectilinear motion down the screw along its thread . upon reaching the bottom most point I want to make a system in which there will be a cam like motion and a three jaw chuck will move outwards . its just like spinning a key , to lock the lock type . Now I need to somehow connect the motion of the motor at the lowest point to just move the key by 45 degrees or perhaps less to produce such motion .
How will I design a mechanical model in which a body just moves by small angle then stops by itself , without using sensors or electric components (except the motor) , plz help me , my language is not good , but I know about my problem .

Comment: Check if you could transform the vertical motion to horizontal by applying the idea of the scissor mechanism of an extending boxing glove https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qjax_7lNlcc

Comment: ok , ill definately check it out , thanks my friend